# Given same value in one column, concatenate remaining rows?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the pandas DataFrame:

```
name   hobby   since
paul   A       1995 
john   A       2005 
paul   B       2015
mary   G       2013
chris  E       2005
chris  D       2001
paul   C       1986
```

I would like to get:

```
name   hobby1   since1    hobby2   since2    hobby3   since3
paul   A        1995      B        2015      C        1986 
john   A        2005      NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN
mary   G        2013      NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN
chris  E        2005      D        2001      NaN      NaN
```

I.e. I would like to have one row per name. The maximum number of hobbies a person can have, say 3 in this case, is something I know in advance. What would be the most elegant/short way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cumcount` and `unstack`. Finally, use `multiindex.map` to join 2-level columns to one level

```
df1 = df.set_index(['name', df.groupby('name').cumcount().add(1)]) \
        .unstack().sort_index(1,level=1)

df1.columns = df1.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)


Out[812]:
      hobby1  since1 hobby2  since2 hobby3  since3
name
chris      E  2005.0      D  2001.0    NaN     NaN
john       A  2005.0    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
mary       G  2013.0    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
paul       A  1995.0      B  2015.0      C  1986.0
```

Comment: this generalized really well for my actual use case. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can first [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and then , [`groupby.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to add to the `variable` and then pivot using [`pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
m=df.melt('name')
(m.assign(variable=m.variable+(m.groupby(['name','variable']).cumcount()+1).astype(str))
 .pivot_table(index='name',columns='variable',values='value',aggfunc='first')
.rename_axis(None,axis=1))
```

---

```
      hobby1 hobby2 hobby3 since1 since2 since3
name                                           
chris      E      D    NaN   2005   2001    NaN
john       A    NaN    NaN   2005    NaN    NaN
mary       G    NaN    NaN   2013    NaN    NaN
paul       A      B      C   1995   2015   1986
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! The only problem: it would be important to have the ordering "hobby1 since1 hobby2 since2 hobby3 since3" instead of "hobby1 hobby2 hobby3 since1 since2 since3".

Comment: @lumpy you can try assigning the code to `m` and then do `m[sorted(m.columns,key=lambda x: x[-1])]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? But you would need to rename the columns after with this solution.

```
df["combined"] = [ "{}_{}".format(x,y) for x,y in zip(df.hobby,df.since)]
df.groupby("name")["combined"]
  .agg(lambda x: "_".join(x))
  .str.split("_",expand=True)
```

The result is:

```
       0     1     2     3     4     5
name
chris  E  2005     D  2001  None  None
john   A  2005  None  None  None  None
mary   G  2013  None  None  None  None
paul   A  1995     B  2015     C  1986
```